# How exactly does addStretch work in QBoxLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, pyqt, qboxlayout

I'm doing a PyQt4 tutorial about box layouts. But I dont understand how `addStretch` works.

- If i use `vbox.addStretch(1)` and `hbox.addStretch(1)`, the two buttons appear down-right. Why?
- if i comment `vbox.addStretch(1)` and `hbox.addStretch(1)` out, the two buttons appear in the center of my window, and they're deformable horizontally, but not vertically. Why?
- theres no difference if I change the value "1"... so what does the value do?

Below is the code I'm using:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class BoxLayout(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('box layout')

        ok = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        cancel = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")

        vbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addWidget(ok)
        vbox.addWidget(cancel)

        hbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.resize(100, 100)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
qb = BoxLayout()
qb.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [addStretch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) method adds a [QSpacerItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html) to the end of a box layout. A QSpacerItem is an adjustable blank space.

1. Using `vbox.addStretch(1)` will add a zero-width spacer-item that
   expands vertically from the top of the layout downwards.

   Using `hbox.addStretch(1)` will add a zero-height spacer-item that
   expands horizontally from the left of the layout rightwards.
2. Without stretch, the layout will be determined by the
   [sizePolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop)
   of the widgets. For a QPushButton, this is
   [QSizePolicy.Fixed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum)
   for the vertical dimension, and
   [QSizePolicy.Minimum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum)
   for the horizontal dimension. If you wanted the buttons to expand in
   both directions, you could do something like this:

   ```
       ok.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
       cancel.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
   ```
3. The argument passed to addStretch changes the stretch factor. If you
   add a second stretch after the ok button:

   ```
       vbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
       vbox.addStretch(1)
       vbox.addWidget(ok)
       vbox.addStretch(2)
       vbox.addWidget(cancel)
   ```

   you will see that the second spacer item grows twice as fast as the
   first. And if you set the first stretch to zero, it won't grow at
   all.

If you want more information, see the [Layout Management](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/layout.html) article in the Qt docs. It's also a good idea to use [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) to experiment with stuff like this, as it gives you immediate visual feedback and shows you all the default values of the various properties involved.